# Excel formula difference in two numbers in steps

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am looking for a formula in Excel that could tell me the change between two numbers in steps. Basically if `A1` was 10 and `A10` was 100, I would like `A2:A9` to auto populate with the step differences, i.e., `A2=20`, `A3=30` `A4=40` respectively.

Comment: select all 10 cell then: Home → Fill → Series → Linear

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should show that you have searched some solutions, and explain why it doesn't work for you. Please take some time to browse this page: https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=(A$10-A$1)/(ROW($A$10)-ROW($A$1))*ROW(A1)+A$1
```

[image]